# How can the current language be added to an extbase redirect?

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my extbase controller action, I want to redirect to another controller/action after a file has been uploaded, so I call

```
$this->redirect('index', 'Download', null, null, $this->settings['listView']);
```

Problem is, that the current language parameter gets lost during the redirect. The method signature allows an array of `$arguments` on the fourth position, but if I put in `L` there

```
$this->redirect('index', 'Download', null, array('L' => $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid), $this->settings['listView']);
```

the redirect wraps this with the extension parameter stuff like

```
&tx_myext_controller[L]=0
```

So my question is: **How can I add the current language to an extbase redirect?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just quick tip I often use when want to *escape* the name space of `$this->redirect` method. I'm using `$this->redirectToUri($uri)`, where `$uri` is prepared with `uriBuilder` (which probably is more flexible then common redirect).

```
$this->uriBuilder->reset()->setArguments(array('L' => $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid))->setTargetPageUid($this->settings['listView']);
$uri = $this->uriBuilder->uriFor('index', array(), 'Download');
$this->redirectToUri($uri);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but isn't this a bug anyway if I have `L` added to my `config.linkVars` in typoscript. In my opinion the language (or whatever is defined in linkVars) should be added there as well.

Comment: Hm, weird, I just checked: `config.linkVars = L` in my TS causes that  `$this->redirect('other')` works as required without need for using `uriBuilder`, TYPO3 ver. 6.1.x, common extension built with the Extension Builder

Comment: The site I'm working on still runs 4.7, that may be the problem. One more reason to convince the customer to do an upgrade :-)